# File Not Found ,Could not load or find Assembly System.Net 2.0.5.0

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, system.net

I have made the MVC4 application.

In the application , I am getting the data from GoogleAPI so I am using DotNetOpenAuth for Authentication and I have added the System.Net 2.1.10.0 assembly.

Its working fine when we deployed into IIS 7, but when I deployed to IIS 6 it gives error but I don't have Mapping errors.

Application is running and I am getting error of Assembly reference .

```
Error Msg - Could not load or Find assembly System.Net 2.0.5.0 , The given assembly reference  is invalid .
```

Stack Trace - [FileLoadException]: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047) at SkyoApp.SkyoApp.DashBoardController.GetChartData(DateTime Fromdate, DateTime Todate, String BusinessPartner, String Type) in D:\Santosh\Projects\SkyoApp from Repository\SkyoApp\SkyoApp\Controllers\DashBoardController.vb:line 256 at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass42.b*_41() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass37.<>c_*DisplayClass39.b*_33() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass4f.b*_49() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass37.b*_36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c_*DisplayClass1d.b*_18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c_*DisplayClass4.b*_3(IAsyncResult ar) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: Perhaps, it is duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246475/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-windows-version-2-0-5-0

Comment: Please, read it first, then ask a question.http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

Nope. This is not a duplicate question.

The answer may be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=378#makechanges